# How to adjust column widths, center column headings for glossaries?

Tags: glossaries

I am using the glossaries package to create a List of Symbols. What I want is two titled columns with the names symbol and description. However, I want the actual symbols to be centered and not left aligned. I also want to increase the width of the symbol column and I want to center the description header, but keep the actual descriptions left aligned.

Here is an MWE of what I currently have:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{longheader}
\renewcommand*{\entryname}{Symbol}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{deg}{name=$^\circ$, description={Degree}}
\newglossaryentry{grav}{name={1D}, description={Normal gravity environment}}
\newglossaryentry{wf}{name={\textit{f}}, description={Wear factor}}

\begin{document}

This is my example.
\Gls{wf}

\gls{grav}

100\glspl{deg}

\printglossary[nonumberlist]


\end{document}
```

This code produces this:
[image]

But I want my List of Symbols page to look like this:
[image]

I know that it is possible to define a new style for glossaries, but I do not have much experience with `LaTeX` and could not figure out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach using `long-booktabs` style and customize the column width and adjustment. `longtable` is better if you have more than one page of list symbols. If you don't like the rules, you can delete them from `\glossaryheader`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\entryname}{Symbol}
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{% define custom glossaries style for Abbreviation page, read relative manual before change
\setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{longtable}{@{}P{3cm}@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-3cm}@{}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%

\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
\toprule \bfseries Symbol & \centering\bfseries Description \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead \bottomrule\endfoot}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{deg}{name=$^\circ$, description={Degree}}
\newglossaryentry{grav}{name={1D}, description={Normal gravity environment}}
\newglossaryentry{wf}{name={\textit{f}}, description={Wear factor}}


\begin{document}

This is my example.
\Gls{wf}

\gls{grav}

100\glspl{deg}

\printglossary[title={\centering List of Symbols},toctitle=List of Symbols,style=mystyle,,nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. This helped out. I ended up removing the toprule, midrule, and bottomrule and customized the spacing a bit. But, your code helped me get to what I needed.